# BootstrapTable: pegar o data-index pela row obtida pelo método getSelections

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, plugin

Tenho uma tabela no meu projeto onde utilizo o plugin [BoostrapTable](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/), que tem uma coluna com radio button ativado (data-radio="true").

Para recuperar os dados do registro marcado na tabela via javascript uso o método `$(tabela).bootstrapTable('getSelections')` e obtenho a "row" selecionada.

Porém, como faço para obter o valor do atributo data-index (gerado pelo próprio plugin)?

(preciso do data-index para que em outro momento eu possa marcar o radiobutton novamente)

Comment: Estranho, eu deu uma lida na documentação do link aí, e não achei este **data-index**.

Comment: O index da linha da tabela que ele sempre cita na documentação é guardado em um atributo criado pelo próprio plugin chamado "data-index", na tag <tr> (algumas outras tags podem ter esse atributo tb). Mas já consegui achar uma solução para o meu problema, deixei abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui, fui direto pelo DOM usando jQuery, sem usar um método do plugin, para recuperar o index da linha:

$(tabela input[name='btSelectItem']:checked").attr("data-index")